# TypeError (can't convert Array into String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, json

In my controller I have the following on line 20:

```
  data = JSON.parse(params[:error])
```

I am trying to take the post and format the results to JSON so that I can then do something like this:

```
  title = data['title']
```

But this 500s with the following below

```
Started POST "/api/services/"
Processing by Api::ServicesController#create as XML

Parameters: {"{\"error\":{\"id\":313131313,\"title\":\"# (Test-20) \\\"Test message-20\\\"\",\"sub_title\":null,\"app\":{\"id\":313131,\"name\":\"site.com\"},\"last_occurrence\":{\"id\":3131313133,\"request_method\":null,\"url\":null,\"occurred_at\":\"2012-11-30T04:27:01 00:00\",\"backtrace\":null},\"environment\":null,\"first_occurred_at\":\"2012-11-30T04:27:01 00:00\",\"last_occurred_at\":\"2012-11-30T04:27:01 00:00\",\"url\":\"http://getexl.com/123\"}}"=>nil, "token"=>"xxxxxx"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

TypeError (can't convert Array into String):
  app/controllers/api/services_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  lib/rack/ie_redirect.rb:19:in `call'
```

Any ideas on how I can format this post correctly to JSON? Thanks

Comment: How are you making this request to this controller? It would be really helpful to see this request's code. The problem right now is because you're attempting to use `[]` on a string, not a hash. Look at the params, it s string.

Comment: The post to my server is coming from a 3rd party whose has an API doc stating "will send a JSON object containing information" does that answer the question? The token part at the end is from my routes.rb, match "/api/services/:token" => "services#create"

Comment: Seems to be the posted data and param from the rails routes are not being combined by rails correctly. Is there a way to tell the rails route that the post is JSON?

Comment: What I don't understand is why the params have this towards the end "}}"=>nil, "

Comment: What URL that the 3rd party is making a request to? Does it end in .json?